# Strange characters seen when sending mail in Italian language using Javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail

Strange characters seen after equal to sign when sending mail in Italian language using Javamail. Could anyone suggest code to send mail in italian language using javamail?

Email body is as below

```
    
    
    
    
    Ciao Dibyendu Biswas,


    Abbiamo ricevuto una richiesta di reimpostazione della sua password Validac=
    tor.


    Rei=
    mposta Password


    Se ignori questo messaggio, la password non verr=C3=A0 reimpostata.


    Se non hai richiesto la reimpostazione della password, Comunicacelo
```

Below is the java mail code I am using to send mail.

```
    public static boolean sendMail (String emailId,String subject,String body,boolean isHtml) {

    boolean status = false;



    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.zoho.com");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    properties.setProperty( "mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
    properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
    properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    properties.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");
    javax.mail.Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(properties,new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
    {   @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
        {   return new PasswordAuthentication(ProductValidationSystemWebConstants.VALIDACTOR_SUPPORT_EMAILID,ProductValidationSystemWebConstants.VALIDACTOR_SUPPORT_PASSWORD);
        }
    });
    try 
    {   MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(ProductValidationSystemWebConstants.VALIDACTOR_SUPPORT_EMAILID));
        message.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(emailId));

        message.setSubject(subject);
        if(isHtml) {
            System.out.println("mail body before: "+body);
            message.setText(body,"UTF-8", "html");
            System.out.println("mail body after: "+body);
        }
        else
            message.setText(body);

        Transport.send(message);

        status = true;
    } 
    catch (MessagingException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return status;
}
```

I use gmail to read the mail. Issue happens when there is any Italian character in the mail content.

Comment: How are you sending the mail and how are you reading and displaying it?  It looks like JavaMail is using quoted-printable encoding for the message (which is reasonable), but the receiver is not decoding the quoted-printable encoding (which it should do).

Comment: I use gmail to read the mail. Issue happens when there is any Italian character in the mail content. I have update my question with the javamail code.

Comment: Fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: Are you using Gmail in a web browser to read the message?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?  Are you sending an html message or a plain text message?  What version of JavaMail are you using?

Comment: I will check the common javamail mistakes - thanks. To answer your questions: - Yes we using gmail in web browser. we are sending html email. Javamail version - 1.4.3.

Comment: If possible, you should upgrade to the [current version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home); 1.4.3 is over 7 years old.  And post the debug output so we can see what's really being sent.

Comment: If you're going to upgrade, don't stop at 1.5.4, go all the way to 1.5.6.  The log is still from the older version.  It looks like you're running a Red Hat version of JavaMail 1.4.5.  Your code shows that you're setting the charset to UTF-8, but the message is using Cp1252, so something else is wrong.  Perhaps it's a bug in the older version or a bug that Red Hat introduced in their version.  Still, I can't see any reason that Gmail would fail to interpret and display the message correctly.

Comment: Also, change your password immediately.  It's exposed in encoded form in the debug output.

Comment: problem solved by changing MimeMessage Object properties.
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit